# Creating a .wsp for SharePoint 2013 from a SP2010 compatible project

Tags: 2013, development, solution-package, wspbuilder

I have a rather old SharePoint project that I believe goes back to SP2007, and is currently working fine with SP2010. My current process for creating a .wsp for sp2010 is to use WSPBuilder. It seems that WSPBuilder is not compatible with SP2013/.net4.

What can I do to 1) have VS13 build a wsp, this old project needs to be migrated into an SP2013 project? or 2) can I create the wsp manually or through a plugin like WSPBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Use a makeCab utility to create one & try to use it. Before that I suggest you to extract a SP 2013 compatible .WSP & see all the artifacts present & whether they match your old .WSP inner files.

Comment: Thanks.. wasn't wanting to do this since the manifest would be a pain to setup, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Please add more details to this answer regarding how to accomplish what you propose